# Sign file with .der-Certificate and create signature (pkcs#7)

Tags: openssl, certificate, sign, pkcs#7, der

The thing I would like to do is:

- Sign a zip-file with openssl using a certificate and create a signature-file (pkcs#7)

What I have/I did so far:

1. I installed openssl and opened the console
2. I created a rsa key (openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048)
3. I created a request (openssl req -batch -sha256 -new -key key.pem
   -out request.pem –subj '/C=../ST=../L=../O=../OU=../CN=..')
4. I sent this request to someone who did any magic with the request
   and sent me an file named 'certificate.der'. When I open this file there are some information like oscp-url and things like this.

So far, so good. Next my naive approach is to sign the zip-file with this certificate and tell openssl to create the pkcs#7-signature so I can verify it using the ocsp-responder.
But I have really not the foggiest notion whether the approach is correct and how to sign the zip-file. :-( If I have errors in reasoning please also let me know. :-)

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use openssl to do that. Use the command

```
openssl.exe smime -sign -binary -in file.zip -signer certificate.der -inkey key.pem -outform DER -out file.p7b
```

You can verify the signature using openssl with this command

```
openssl.exe smime -verify -binary -inform DER -in file.p7b -content file.zip -noverify > nul
```

For more information read openssl manual [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/smime.html)

Comment: This command shows an error-message: unable to load certificate
5456:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_rea
.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Comment: Converting the der-file to pem and execute the command did the job - thanks!

Comment: openssl expects pem format by default, but if you add `-inform der` to the command, you can use certificates in der format as well.